# Как сделать такую фигуру

Tags: javascript, html, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста сделать такую фигуру особенно border такого цветас прозрачностью вначале

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #c49107 15%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  color: white;
  width: 320px;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #c49107 #c49107 transparent;
  border-width: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">Регистрируйся иначе все пропустишь</div>
```

Comment: Бро если не сложно можешь подсказать как другую фигуру сверстать ?